# My pc (or monitor) freeze for no reason

Tags: desktop-computer

Hello there i recently had problem with my pc, this never happened before.
 When i run it for some time or play games etc.
Usually after few hours , my monitor just became black and i got message "Entering sleeping mode" and pc is still on and it start beeping. 
I cant leave sleeping mode nor anything work so i need to restart pc.
Anyone know what is problem its really annoying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway i use fan now and i run pc whole day on fan speed 3 and it wont shutdown so its probably overheating 
Here : https://postimg.org/image/4j1jacksx/

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be an overheating problem (I've had my own share). The BIOS itself causes this.

Any pattern in the beeping?

Comment: Yes i tought that too but i cleaned whole pc and cooler but well i need more cooling i guess?Beeping noise umm its always same like when there is bug and it repeat bumbumbum ( cant explain better) what is temeprature when it turn off?

Comment: Are the beeps short or long? Also the motherboard should explain this more (there is nothing universal)

Comment: Beeps are long and not stopping untill i restart , i opened pc and put fan and i got like -10°C than before, i will tell here if it still happen

Comment: Edit: Well it happen again , this time with no beep sound , i noticed that my keyboard dont work when it happen (maybe mouse im not sure)so idk what to do it just started happening at summer idk what could go wrong?

Comment: Can overheating protection be disabled? My old PC used to shutdown at 80C before that was enabled.

Comment: (BIOS settings)